# SSL certificate on NginX

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https

I have a DO droplet with nginX running 8 node apps as proxy servers.

For one of those i have a specific domain (e.g. 192.22.XX.20: 8888 -> mydomain.com) and I need HTTPS to get audio from users mic.

I have a PositiveSSL certificate defined on NginX but when i try to use it on that node app, nothing works. What Am I doing wrong?

nginx.default.conf

`...
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/.../ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/.../private.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
...
    #proxy to a node app running on 8005 port
    location /interpretame/ {
      #return 301 $scheme://localhost:8005$request_uri;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8005/;
    }`

node app.js

```
...

```
var https_options = {
 ca: fs.readFileSync("./cert/example_ca.crt"),
 key: fs.readFileSync("./cert/example.key"),
 cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert/example.crt")
};
```

...

```
https.createServer(https_options, app).listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Listening over HTTPS at ' + port);
});
```

```

Answer (score 0):

How do you define the 'nothing works'? :)

The application does not boot at all? If yes, it is quite possible that this happens if you start the application with `node app.js`. You have to start the application with `sudo node app.js` and by the way this is very bad practice.

Comment: I can see that the node app is up and running. How should i do that?